# Cannot Increase WP Memory Limit

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, memory-limit

I would like to increase `memory_limit` to `512M` but it's not working for me. I'm using WampServer. This is what I have done:

- In `.htaccess` I added `php_value memory_limit 512M` at the bottom.
- In `php.ini` located in `D:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10` I have `memory_limit = 512M`.
- In wp-config.php, I added `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );` at the bottom.

However, a plugin still shows that I have 40M as it recommend that I have at least 128MB. This is what I have in the `defult-constants.php`

```
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );
    }
}
```

Comment: did you restart apache after changing the config values?

Comment: oh wait; `at the bottom`, you mean _after_ `wp-settings.php` is included? In that case; `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` will already be set (and cannot be changed again). Probably an error is fired, but it is hidden by default

Comment: restart apache? means restart the server,right?

Comment: yeah, `WAMP` stands for; `Windows-Apache-MySQL-PHP`. It's the full stack. Restarting the whole server should work, but just apache should do the trick. Only necessary when you change `php.ini` values (or `httpd.conf` for that matter).

Comment: In wp-config.php I add "define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );" below " require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');"

Comment: Yes, I restart Wamp many times.

Comment: you should put that rule _above_ that line, because in `wp-settings.php` the memory limit is already set

Comment: Please see my answer below. I don't understand why it works with this, why I added to the other files, it doesn't work for me. Now it works. The plugin now shows up the message that I have sufficient memory in order to use the plugin.

Comment: hey I've followed your instruction to put it above that line. I also works! as I removed what I have done in defult-constants.php to check. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is that I didn't early add it above that line, right?

Comment: yup :) I'll flash you an answer with explanation why it didn't work a bit later

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an answer. Just enter `512M` in `defult-constants.php`

```
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M' );
    }
}
```

So now I have

```
    if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against it. This will be overwritten with your next wordpress upgrade... it _should_ be in your wp-config.php. Read my comment above, that could be your problem

Comment: Yes, sir. I already removed it :) Thanks so much. I am newbie.